# Base Controller error

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I made a base controller and this error comes out.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Form::$session

Filename: core/MY_Controller.php

Line Number: 7

Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_intro\application\core\MY_Controller.php on line 7

MY_Controller is this:

```
      <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

             class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
             function __construct(){
                 parent::__construct();

                     $user_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
                      $this->data['uname'] = $this->user_lib->get($id);
                 }
              }
```

What seems to be the problem here?Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you load your `session` library in your `autoload.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `session` library in your controller.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Or

you can add it by default for whole project in

`/application/config/autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Also, go to `/application/config/config.php` and add a encryption key for you application:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'YOUR-ENCRYPTION-KEY';
```

Comment: I did that and this error comes out:   An Error Was Encountered

In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file.

Comment: I don't know how to set an encryption key in my config file. Can you help me?

Comment: Can I put any key to it?

Comment: Yes, you can put any key. More long and more special characters. This will make your application more secure.

Comment: Thanks! I used the codeigniter key generator as I have read from the comments of others.

Comment: Another problem though, my user_lib. It says undefined property.

Comment: I think, this is the model you want to load. Please load it first. :)

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks! But what if I want to put a login form, where should I put it?Do I have to put it in MY_Controller or Student_Controller under MY_Controller?I don't fully understand how the base controller works.